# How to uncheck all other check boxes except only one box ?

Tags: android

I have two check boxes in a alert dialog box. What I want is that if one of the checkbox is clicked then other checkbox gets unchecked automatically. Only one checkbox can be clicked at a time. I've searched the internet and tried multiple solutions but no solution is working.

Comment: Why don't you use RadioGroup for it .Cause its made for such behavior .

Comment: You have to uncheck other programmatically when you check one..

Comment: I've tried but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find ids of your check boxs...
checkBoxOne= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
checkBoxTwo= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

checkBoxOne.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
           Here you unchecked the other check boxes   
            checkBoxTwo.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});

checkBoxTwo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
           Here you unchecked the other check boxes
            checkBoxOne.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a CheckBox you have to programmatically uncheck the other button:

```
private void createCustomDialogCheckBox() {

    LinearLayout dialogLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    dialogLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    final CheckBox checkBoxOption1 = new CheckBox(this);
    final CheckBox checkBoxOption2 = new CheckBox(this);

    checkBoxOption1.setText("Option 1");
    checkBoxOption2.setText("Option 2");

    checkBoxOption1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            CheckBox otherCheckBox = checkBoxOption2;
            if(isChecked && otherCheckBox.isChecked()){
                otherCheckBox.setChecked(!otherCheckBox.isChecked());
            }
        }
    });

    checkBoxOption2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            CheckBox otherCheckBox = checkBoxOption1;
            if(isChecked && otherCheckBox.isChecked()){
                otherCheckBox.setChecked(!otherCheckBox.isChecked());
            }
        }
    });

    dialogLayout.addView(checkBoxOption1);
    dialogLayout.addView(checkBoxOption2);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogLayout);
    dialogBuilder.show();
}
```

A better solution is to use RadioButton with does all this automatically:

```
private void createCustomDialogRadioButton() {

    LinearLayout dialogLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    dialogLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    RadioButton radioButtonOption1 = new RadioButton(this);
    RadioButton radioButtonOption2 = new RadioButton(this);

    radioButtonOption1.setText("Option 1");
    radioButtonOption2.setText("Option 2");

    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);

    // radio buttons must be on the same radio group
    // so that other buttons will automatically be unchecked / unselected

    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonOption1);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonOption2);

    dialogLayout.addView(radioGroup);

    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogLayout);
    dialogBuilder.show();
}
```